# OpenCL - Profile a Visual Studio native unit test using NSight

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, opencl, nsight

I would like to profile an OpenCL code using NVidia's NSight.

The obstacle is that the OpenCL code runs from a Visual Studio native unit test.

NSight requires setting the 'Application', 'Arguments' and 'Working directory'.

Using Visual Studio 2015, to run native unit tests from the command line it is suggested to run: vstest.console.exe

The problem when trying to invoke it, NSight says it cannot run an MSIL program.

What is the native application that executes the unit tests?

(A workaround which I don't want to do is it create another project as a console application which invokes the test code and profile it)

Regards,

Tomer Gal, CTO at OpTeamizer